# 3 columns enumitem description

Tags: multicol, enumitem, description

As part of an article, I am translating a text from an oriental language to German. I am writing the short introduction and then follows the text. Thus, I wanted to place it in a table with two columns and two lines. In other paragraphs, I will need three columns (Greek - Syriac - English) - how can I have both codes in the same text? A user has shown me a very situable solutions for 2 columns, so I need to add a separate code with 3 columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{translation}{description}{1}
\setlist[translation]{align=parleft, labelwidth=*, leftmargin=14em, font=\normalfont, before=\raggedright}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{translation}

    \item[\textbf{English}] \textbf{German}
    
    \item[One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he discovered that in bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous bug. He lay on his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a little, his brown, arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections.]

    Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt. Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken und sah, wenn er den Kopf ein wenig hob, seinen gewölbten, braunen, von bogenförmigen Versteifungen geteilten Bauch, auf dessen Höhe sich die Bettdecke, zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten bereit, kaum noch erhalten konnte. Seine vielen, im Vergleich zu seinem sonstigen Umfang kläglich dünnen Beine flimmerten ihm hilflos vor den Augen.

    \item[``What's happened to me,'' he thought. It was no dream.]

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{translation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the packages in the [Parallel](https://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel) category on CTAN. At first glance, [`parcolumns`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) and [`paracol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) seem to offer that functionality.